# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer Unhandled exception rendering component

Tags: c#, mudblazor

I'm working on MudBlazor Wasm-hosted project. I'm doing server-side pagination.

I got an error like this:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: The given header was not found.
> System.InvalidOperationException: The given header was not found.
> at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.GetValues(HeaderDescriptor descriptor)
> at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.GetValues(String name)
> at MudPage.Client.HttpRepository.HttpClientRepository.GetUserTables(Parameters
> parameters) in
> C:\Users\hamsa\OneDrive\Documents\Hams\Csharp\Mudblazor\MudPage\MudPage\Client\HttpRepository\HttpClientRepository.cs:line 36

```cs
public class HttpClientRepository : IHttpClientRepository
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly JsonSerializerOptions _options;

    public HttpClientRepository(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
        _options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    }

    public async Task<PagingResponse<UserTable>> GetUserTables(Parameters parameters)
    {
        var queryStringParam = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["pageNumber"] = parameters.PageNumber.ToString(),
            ["pageSize"] = parameters.PageSize.ToString(),
            ["searchTerm"] = parameters.SearchTerm ?? "",
            ["orderBy"] = parameters.OrderBy ?? "name"
        };

        using (var response = await _client.GetAsync(QueryHelpers
        .AddQueryString("usertables", queryStringParam)))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var metaData = JsonSerializer
                .Deserialize<MetaData>(response.Headers.GetValues("X-Pagination").First(), _options);

            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            var pagingResponse = new PagingResponse<UserTable>
            {
                Items = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<UserTable>>(stream, _options),
                MetaData = metaData
            };

            return pagingResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Exactly it shows an error in this line:

```
var metaData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MetaData>(response.Headers.GetValues("X-Pagination").First(), _options);
```

But I couldn't figure out what exactly it is.